# access- need a combo box to appear in a form when a toggle button is clicked

Tags: forms, combobox, ms-access-2010, togglebutton

i have a form which you select one toggle button from a choice of 4 i would like one of the 4 when selected to offer a drop down

I am trying to unlock a combobox when a option button is enabled.

I am hoping to find a way to simultaneously click the option button in the userform and have it unlock the combo boxes next to them

Answer (score 0):

You can change the combo box's `.Enabled` property:

```
Private Sub tgl1_Click()
    Me!Combo3.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

You may also want to check the value of the toggle button:

```
Private Sub tgl1_Click()
    If tgl1 = False Then
        Me!Combo3.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me!Combo3.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards,